# filter data by str.contains

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to filter my large data by columns that may contains the following strings 'io' and 'ir'.

df1

```
index  aio   bir   ckk
1      2     3     4
2      3     4     5
```

I want to create a new df with columns that contain 'io' and 'ir.
The new df should look :

```
index  aio   bir  
1      2     3    
2      3     4
```

I tried

```
df = df[:, str.contains('io','ir')]
```

but I got an error saying type object 'str' has no attribute 'contains'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

with `pd.DataFrame.filter`

```
df.filter(regex='i(o|r)')

       aio  bir
index          
1        2    3
2        3    4
```

If you have a list of things to match

```
things = ['io', 'ir']
df.filter(regex='|'.join(things))

       aio  bir
index          
1        2    3
2        3    4
```

### Alternatives

```
df.filter(regex='io|ir')
```

---

```
df.loc[:, df.columns.str.contains('io|ir')]
```

Comment: I tried this way. I can do it with only one words >  df.filter(like='io', axis=0) or with the way you mentioned . However, I struggle when the filter contains way many more words such as 'km','dt','if','do'. how do I combine all of these in the filter.

Comment: I updated my post with a guess at what you mean.  Otherwise, you'll need to show an example of what you mean.

Comment: Is str.contain time costing function? I test my solution and filter , filter is much faster  ...

Comment: Thank you so much. I think the problem was that I write the code this way : df.filter(regex='io'|'or') ;  also, df.loc[:, df.columns.str.contains('io'|'or')], Thank you a lot. Now I understand that I should have written it this way 'io|ir'

Answer (score 1):

Since you mention `str.contains`

```
df.loc[:,df.columns.str.contains('io|ir')]
Out[354]: 
       aio  bir
index          
1        2    3
2        3    4
```